# RecyclerView with ItemTouchHelper only part swipeable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

I have a recyclerview list with items like this:

[image: list item]

The red square **only** can we swiped (drag and drop out) to the left, and the green **only** can we swiped to the right.  When the element is swiped, appear and image with a option like this:

-swipe left:

[image: swipe left]

-swipe right:
[image: swipe right]

The layout item have this appearance:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
      <ImageView/> //Red square
      <ImageView/>  //Green square
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout>
      <ImageView/>  //Red square swiped action
      <ImageView/>  //Green square swiped action
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to do this with `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` and overriding the method `onChildDraw` to make the correct animation. But I can't hold with square has be swiped, and make the correct animation.
¿Another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a lot of examples, it's easy by creating you own Callback listener in RecycleView. Just as in [this example](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.8ebuzl8qr). You need to provide you own behavior.

Example of SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback from link above.

```
    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;

        //Four your Red field use flags
        int redFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START;

        //Four your Green field use flags
        int greenFlags = ItemTouchHelper.END;

        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }
```

Comment: How I can know if I must `return  makeMovementFlahs(0,redFlags)` or `return  makeMovementFlahs(0, greenFlags)` ? how i can know where the movement start/ end (red or green square)?

Comment: You need just startDrag action on needed you view. I think you don't know, how that callback working... You should use this example, for more information https://github.com/GensaGames/Sample-KenBurnsEffect-in-RecycleView

Comment: I have seen the example. I'm using a `OnTouchListener` to detect the detect the swipes in the red and green square, then I call `startDrag()` and all works fine. But I dont know how to disable the other swipes movements, because the callback, is called always or how to return 0,0 in the method `getMovementFlags`